# Does solr store recent queries?

Tags: solr, solrj

For example I fired queries-

```
q=id:SOURCE-*
q=sourceName:abc
q=sourceName:xyz
q=id:DB-*
```

Is there any way to fetch these last 4 queries fired on Solr?

Answer (score 1):

Solr does has a [query cache](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/query-settings-in-solrconfig.html) that holds the previous queries and the docs ids with the results. Your main issue would be how to use it, as it is mostly for internal use. But you can look into the source code and maybe you find a way.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I checked Solr cache. It is useful if I want to save query/filter query results in the cache. But its too much overhead to retrieve only query keywords.

Answer (score 1):

One idea might be to use the [Solr logging system](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/configuring-logging.html). You can set the log level to `INFO` and it should be fine to retrieve every queries.

> In addition to the logging options [...], there is a way to
>   configure which request parameters (such as parameters sent as part of
>   queries) are logged with an additional request parameter called
>   [`logParamsList`](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/common-query-parameters.html#CommonQueryParameters-ThelogParamsListParameter). See the section on [Common Query Parameters](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/common-query-parameters.html#CommonQueryParameters-ThelogParamsListParameter) for more
>   information.

For example with `logParamsList=q`, only the `q` parameters will be logged.

**N.B.** Logging every query can potentially impact performance depending on the query rate and the volume of data generated.

Comment: Thanks. I will check that